# pyodbc truncates column names

Tags: python, teradata, pyodbc

I'm using python 3.6.2, pyodbc 4.0.23, to access Teradata 15.10.07.15 on Ubuntu 16.04. The teradata driver I have installed is tdodbc1620     16.20.00.36-1 amd64        SIMBA Teradata ODBC driver package for Ubuntu.

When I run the following:

```
>>>pyodbc.pooling = False
>>>conn_str="autocommit=True;ANSI=True;PWD=xxx;UID=xxx;DATABASE=xxx;LOGINTIMEOUT=300;DBCNAME=xxx;DRIVER=Teradata;SERVER=x.x.x)"
>>>conn=pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
>>>conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin')
>>>conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='latin')
>>>conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WMETADATA, encoding='latin')
>>>conn.setencoding(encoding='latin')
>>>cur =  conn.cursor()

>>>sql5 = """SELECT IP3_addr, cntry_name, city_name FROM tns_access_views.DW_TNS_IP_ADDR_GEO_LOC_LKP where cntry_name in (xxx) """
>>>ip = pandas.io.sql.read_sql(sql5,conn)

>>>ip.columns

Index(['IP3_', 'CNTRY', 'CITY_'], dtype='object')
```

I'm expecting IP3_addr, cntry_name, city_name.  Any idea why it is shortening the column names?

Comment: You might want to ask about this on [GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues) and provide an [ODBC trace log](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Troubleshooting:-Generating-an-ODBC-trace-log).

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the [Teradata ODBC driver](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/odbc-driver/linux)?

Answer (score 1):

A little late but since I didn't find this question or answer elsewhere...
It seems this is an encoding issue.
I was able to resolve it in my case by adding this line before running the query:

connection.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WMETADATA, encoding='utf-16le')

Answer (score 0):

Curious whether you have solved this problem.  I once had this problem and resolved it by downgrading to `pyodbc=3.0.7`.  However, I couldn't do it anymore.  It seems like this version of Pyodbc is not found anywhere in Anaconda channels.